# truncating text, ignoring child nodes javascript

Tags: javascript, truncate

I'm trying to truncate a string within a div that also contains a span tag, but my script is gathering up the span tag converting it to text and pushing it back, how do I ignore the child data in a tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="oo-roboto-override row-title">
    <span class="hidden-lg-up" itemprop="name">
        Title: 
    </span>
    This is the text that I want to truncate
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        $(".row-title").each( function() {
            var g = (this).innerHTML;
            var x = ". . . ";
            var leng = 50;
            var html = g.substring(0, leng)+"";
            var allHTML = html+x;
            $(this).text(allHTML);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate text nodes:

```js
$(".row-title").each(function() {
  var leng = 25;
  [].forEach.call(this.childNodes, function(child) {
    if(child.nodeType === 3) { // text node
      var txt = child.textContent.trim();
      if(txt.length > leng) {
        child.textContent = txt.substr(0, leng) + "…";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oo-roboto-override row-title">
  <span class="hidden-lg-up" itemprop="name">
    Title: 
  </span>
  This is the text that I want to truncate
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you do not want as result:

***<span class="hidden-lg-up" itemprop="name"> . . .***

but only the text.

If it is like this you may use:

```
var g = $(this).text();
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".row-title").each( function() {
    var g = $(this).text().trim();
    var x = ". . . ";
    var leng = 50;
    var html = g.substring(0, leng)+"";
    var allHTML = html+x;
    $(this).text(allHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="oo-roboto-override row-title">
    <span class="hidden-lg-up" itemprop="name">
        Title:
    </span>
    This is the text that I want to truncate
</div>
```

Because this question is marked as javaScript, this is the snippet in full js:

> [element.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): The Node.textContent property represents the text content of a node and its descendants

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('row-title'), function(element, index) {
    var g = element.textContent.trim().replace(/\n */g, '');
    var x = ". . . ";
    var leng = 50;
    var html = g.substring(0, leng)+"";
    var allHTML = html+x;
    element.textContent = allHTML;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="oo-roboto-override row-title">
    <span class="hidden-lg-up" itemprop="name">
        Title:
    </span>
    This is the text that I want to truncate
</div>
```

Comment: `"This is the text that I want to truncate".length == 40` should not be truncated as your length variable is 50.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo If you see with care the content of the div you may see new lines chars (i.e.: \n) and hidden spaces among them. How to handle this chars? It's required to remove them?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo I updated only the full js snippet and how you can see, removing useless \n with spaces, now the string is no more truncated. But the question is alive: is it right? Let me know

Comment: Well, I didn't make the question. But it seems he just want to truncate the text `This is the text I want to truncate`, also you're now truncating `Title: This is the text I want to truncate`, I think he wants something like @Oriol answer.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo For me it is a pleasure to receive comments. I like your comments. You helped me to reflect more. So, thanks again so much

Comment: That's the pourpose of this website!! Thank you for helping people!! =)